# Remote Hive metastore: Spark connecting to local installation not remote metastore

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-emr, hive-metastore

I have configured remote Hive metastore on RDS running MySQL.
EMR creates fine and is able to connect to RDS instance on 3306 port, but when i create some table it creates it in `default` database.

To verify this, I checked what Hive CLI connects to and to my surprise even that connects to local db and shows only `default` database.

I have set correct javax.jdo.option.* properties  `ConnectionURL`, `ConnectionDriverName`, `ConnectionUserName`, `ConnectionPassword` in `hive-site.xml`

Any idea where I could be wrong?

Comment: Please check if Metastore service is running on the host, you can restart the service using: 'service hive-metastore restart'

Comment: @LakshmanBattini yes the service is running. I tried restarting the service as well but not help